# Conditional unique constraint using annotations

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, unique-constraint

I have two related entities with two different types(GENERAL and CUSTOM) and I save it in the same table. Entity with type GENERAL should have unique values of field name and CUSTOM can have duplicates for different users and not duplicate GENERAL name.
I'm looking for a way to create conditional unique constraint in order to check next cases:

- if entity has type GENERAL, name should be unique
- if entity has type CUSTOM, name can be duplicated in the table but can't duplicate GENERAL items and should be unique for specific user(by user id)

  ```
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "Purpose", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(columnNames = {"purposeId"}))
  @Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
  public class GeneralPurpose {
  ```

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO, generator="purpose_seq_gen")
  @SequenceGenerator(name="purpose_seq_gen", sequenceName="PURPOSE_SEQ")
  @Column(name = "purposeId", nullable = false)
  private long purposeId;

  @Column(name = "type", nullable = false)
  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  private PurposeType type;

  @Column(name = "name", nullable = false)
  private String name;

  ```
  @Entity
  @Table(name = "Purpose")
  public class CustomPurpose extends GeneralPurpose {
  ```

  @ManyToOne()
  @JoinColumn(name="id")
  @JsonIgnore
  private User user;

  ```
  public enum PurposeType {
      GENERAL, CUSTOM
  }
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by adding another column to the Purpose table.  This column is to store a constant value for GENERAL records, and the user id for CUSTOM records.  For GENERAL records, the value could be 0 (if the user id is numeric) or "GENERAL" (if the user id is a string).  It could be named 'userOfRecord' or 'recordDiscriminator', something like that.

Then you can add a unique constraint on [ type, name, userOfRecord ].

Comment: Actually the unique constraint would have to be on [ name, userOfRecord ].

Comment: This is not exactly what I'm looking for. There are a few problems in this solution. If userOfRecord will have unique constraint, I can't be able to save a few GENERAL items since it will have the same id(0). And if I'll add unique constraint to name, a few different users will not be able to save items with the same name

Comment: The constraint is on both the fields, both name and 'userOfRecord'.  Possible rows: ('Tom', 0, 'GENERAL'); ('Dick', 0, 'GENERAL'); ('Harry', 500, 'CUSTOM'); ('Harry', 600, 'CUSTOM').... Since the combination of the two fields must be unique, you can have the two 'Harry' rows, since the 'userOfRecord' is different.  But you can't have two 'Tom', 0, 'GENERAL' rows, since both rows would have 0 as 'userOfRecord'.

Comment: Actually I allready have userOfRecord field and I added unique constraint to this field and to name field. and now it fails when trying to add a record to the same user ("Item name 1", CUSTOM, 1), ("Item name 2", CUSTOM, 1)
`@Column(name = "name", nullable = false, unique = true)
private String name;`
`@ManyToOne()
@JoinColumn(name="id", unique = true)
@JsonIgnore
private User user;`

Comment: Do you have two different unique constraints, one on each field?  Or do you have a single unique constraint with both fields?  On the entity class you should have an annotation like so: `@Table(name = "my_table_name", uniqueConstraints = @UniqueConstraint(name="my_constraint_name", columnNames = {"NAME", "userOfRecord"}))`.  So, only one constraint, listing both fields. Actually I would define the constraint in DDL separately, but the same concept either way... the combination of the two fields must be unique, not either one separately.

Comment: I see from your code snippet that you have each field being unique to itself, but you need for the combination of the two fields to be unique.

Comment: ... And, in your example, the User entity is stored in a different table, so the user id is in that other table; but I don't believe you can add a column from another table to such a unique constraint as I have in mind.  That's why I thought you would have to add another plain @Column column to the base table; it is not really ideal, but it will achieve what you want.